# Replace hardcoded value with variable in calculation

Tags: bash

In the calculation of elapsed time using `$((($(date -f - +%s- <<<$'10:20 tomorrow\nnow')0)%86400))`,  I would like to replace the hardcoded time with a variable but whatever I have tried the backslash is duplicated and the formula does not work. What am I missing here?

I have tried putting the variable in quotes, closing the single quotes around the variable and not including the $ in front of the variable.

**hardcoded:**

```
currenttime=$( date '+%H:%M:%S' )
echo currenttime = $currenttime
starttime="10:20:00"
echo elapsed seconds = $((($(date -f - +%s- <<<$'10:20 tomorrow\nnow')0)%86400))
```

**Using variable:**

```
echo currenttime = $currenttime
starttime="10:20:00"
echo elapsed seconds = $((($(date -f - +%s- <<<$'$starttime tomorrow\nnow')0)%86400))
```

**Hardcoded results:**

currenttime = 15:28:54
elapsed seconds = 67866

currenttime=$( date '+%H:%M:%S' )

**Variable results:**

currenttime = 15:30:03
date: invalid date â$starttime tomorrowâ
elapsed seconds = 52203

Comment: Don't give up the ship! Keep posting, it only gets easier, but read a lot of Q/A here on your tags of interest (`[bash]`), see which ones get voted closed and which ones have good multiple answers/discussions. Some here strive for "one correct answer", I prefer discussions, but that's just IMHO. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

`$'...'` doesn't perform parameter expansion; you need to use double quotes for that part.

For example:

```
echo elapsed seconds = $((($(date -f - +%s- <<<"$starttime tomorrow"$'\n'"now")0)%86400))
```

However, it would be much simpler to just break this into several lines of code:

```
now=$(date +%s)
later=$(date +%s --date "$starttime tomorrow")
echo "elapsed seconds = $(( (later - now) % 86400 ))"
```

or use a here document for multiline input:

```
x=$(( $(date -f- +%s- <<EOF
$starttime tomorrow
now
EOF
)0 % 86400))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. I have however decided to break it down as you suggest as it is much easier to see what's going on. Probably trying to be too clever!